# Java happens-before consistent thread view on two ConcurrentMaps

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a java class to handle a multithreaded subscription service. By implementing the Subscribable interface, tasks can be submitted to the service and periodically executed. A sketch of the code is seen below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Subscribtions {

    private ConcurrentMap<Subscribable, Future<?>> futures = new ConcurrentHashMap<Subscribable, Future<?>>();
    private ConcurrentMap<Subscribable, Integer> cacheFutures = new ConcurrentHashMap<Subscribable, Integer>();
    private ScheduledExecutorService threads;

    public Subscribtions() {
        threads = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(16);
    }

    public void subscribe(Subscribable subscription) {
        Runnable runnable = getThread(subscription);
        Future<?> future = threads.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, subscription.getInitialDelay(), subscription.getPeriod(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        futures.put(subscription, future);
    }

    /*
     * Only called from controller thread
     */
    public void unsubscribe(Subscribable subscription) {
        Future<?> future = futures.remove(subscription);    //1. Might be removed by worker thread 
        if (future != null)
            future.cancel(false);
        else {
            //3. Worker-thread view     := cacheFutures.put() -> futures.remove()
            //4. Controller-thread has seen futures.remove(), but has it seen cacheFutures.put()?
        }
    }

    /*
     * Only called from worker threads
     */
    private void delay(Runnable runnable, Subscribable subscription, long delay) {
        cacheFutures.put(subscription, 0);                  //2. Which is why it is cached first
        Future<?> currentFuture = futures.remove(subscription);
        if (currentFuture != null) {
            currentFuture.cancel(false);
            Future<?> future = threads.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, delay, subscription.getPeriod(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            futures.put(subscription, future);
        }
    }

    private Runnable getThread(Subscribable subscription) {
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Do work...
                boolean someCondition = true;
                long someDelay = 100;
                if (someCondition) {
                    delay(this, subscription, someDelay);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public interface Subscribable {
        long getInitialDelay();
        long getPeriod();
    }
}
```

So the class permits to:

- Subscribe to new tasks
- Unsubscribe from existing tasks
- Delay a periodically executed task

Subscriptions are added/removed by an external controlling thread, but delays are incurred only by the internal worker threads. This could happen, if for instance a worker thread found no update from the last execution or e.g. if the thread only needs to execute from 00.00 - 23.00.

My problem is that a worker thread may call `delay()` and remove its future from the ConcurrentMap, and the controller thread may concurrently call `unsubscribe()`. Then if the controller thread checks the ConcurrentMap before the worker thread has put in a new future, the `unsubscribe()` call will be lost.

There are some (not exhaustive list perhaps) solutions:

- Use a lock between the `delay()` and `unsubscribe()` methods
- Same as above, but one lock per subscribtion
- (preferred?) Use no locks, but "cache" removed futures in the `delay()` method

As for the third solution, since the worker-thread has established the happens-before relationship `cacheFutures.put() -> futures.remove()`, and the atomicity of ConcurrentMap makes the controller thread see `futures.remove()`, does it also see the same happens-before relationship as the worker thread? I.e. `cacheFutures.put() -> futures.remove()`? Or does the atomicity only hold for the `futures` map with updates to other variables being propagated later?

Any other comments are also welcome, esp. considering use of the volatile keyword. Should the cache-map be declared volatile? thanks!

Comment: This question might be a better fit for the code review site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One lock per subscription would require you to maintain yet another map, and possibly thereby to introduce additional concurrency issues.  I think that would be better avoided.  The same applies even more so to caching removed subscriptions, plus that affords the added risk of unwanted resource retention (and note that it's not the `Future`s themselves that you would need to cache, but rather the `Subscribable`s with which they are associated).

Any way around, you will need some kind of synchronization / locking.  For example, in your option (3) you need to avoid an `unsubscribe()` for a given subscription happening between `delay()` caching that subscription and  removing its `Future`.  The only way you could avoid that without some form of locking would be if you could use just one `Future` per subscription, kept continuously in place from the time it is enrolled by `subscribe()` until it is removed by `unsubscribe()`.  Doing so is not consistent with the ability to delay an already-scheduled subscription.

> As for the third solution, since the worker-thread has established the happens-before relationship cacheFutures.put() -> futures.remove(), and the atomicity of ConcurrentMap makes the controller thread see futures.remove(), does it also see the same happens-before relationship as the worker thread?

Happens-before is a relationship between actions in an execution of a program.  It is not specific to any one thread's view of the execution.

> Or does the atomicity only hold for the futures map with updates to other variables being propagated later?

The controller thread will always see the `cacheFutures.put()` performed by an invocation of `delay()` occuring before the `futures.remove()` performed by that same invocation.  I don't think that helps you, though.

> Should the cache-map be declared volatile?

No.  That would avail nothing, because although the *contents* of that map change, the map itself is always the same object, and the reference to it does not change.

You could consider having `subscribe()`, `delay()`, and `unsubscribe()` each synchronize on the `Subscribable` presented.  That's not what I understood you to mean about having a lock per subscription, but it is similar.  It would avoid the need for a separate data structure to maintain such locks.  I guess you could also build locking methods into the `Subscribable` interface if you want to avoid explicit synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `ConcurrentMap` but you aren't using it. Consider something along these lines:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

final class SO33555545
{

  public static void main(String... argv)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    ScheduledExecutorService workers = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(16);
    Subscriptions sub = new Subscriptions(workers);
    sub.subscribe(() -> System.out.println("Message received: A"));
    sub.subscribe(() -> System.out.println("Message received: B"));
    Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
    workers.shutdown();
  }

}

final class Subscriptions
{

  private final ConcurrentMap<Subscribable, Task> tasks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  private final ScheduledExecutorService workers;

  public Subscriptions(ScheduledExecutorService workers)
  {
    this.workers = workers;
  }

  void subscribe(Subscribable sub)
  {
    Task task = new Task(sub);
    Task current = tasks.putIfAbsent(sub, task);
    if (current != null)
      throw new IllegalStateException("Already subscribed");
    task.activate();
  }

  private Future<?> schedule(Subscribable sub)
  {
    Runnable task = () -> {
      sub.invoke();
      if (Math.random() < 0.25) {
        System.out.println("Delaying...");
        delay(sub, 5);
      }
    };
    return workers.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, sub.getPeriod(), sub.getPeriod(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  void unsubscribe(Subscribable sub)
  {
    Task task = tasks.remove(sub);
    if (task != null)
      task.cancel();
  }

  private void delay(Subscribable sub, long delay)
  {
    Task task = new Task(sub);
    Task obsolete = tasks.replace(sub, task);
    if (obsolete != null) {
      obsolete.cancel();
      task.activate();
    }
  }

  private final class Task
  {

    private final FutureTask<Future<?>> future;

    Task(Subscribable sub)
    {
      this.future = new FutureTask<>(() -> schedule(sub));
    }

    void activate()
    {
      future.run();
    }

    void cancel()
    {
      boolean interrupted = false;
      while (true) {
        try {
          future.get().cancel(false);
          break;
        }
        catch (ExecutionException ignore) {
          ignore.printStackTrace(); /* Cancellation is unnecessary. */
          break;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          interrupted = true; /* Keep waiting... */
        }
      }
      if (interrupted)
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); /* Reset interrupt state. */
    }

  }

}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Subscribable
{

  default long getPeriod()
  {
    return 4;
  }

  void invoke();

}
```